# How to handle app termination by user while using URLSession with background configuration?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using standard approach to upload files to the server as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html) in documentation. My concern is, that whenever file is uploading and user is killing app from Multitasking Manager, I would like to be notified that upload failed. So I thought that in this case I the `urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?)` method will be called, but instead nothing is actually called. I assumed that I have properly registered delegate, because in other cases uploading is working fine.

How can I handle app termination by user?

Answer (score 0):

`applicationWillTerminate(_:)` and `applicationWillResignActive(_:)` are best places for you to handle that situation. Refer to [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate) and [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622950-applicationwillresignactive) for more information.

Comment: So neither of the URLSessionDelegate methods will be called?

Comment: Just use URLSessionDelegate as normal. What I mean is you can use those events to get notified before the after terminated.